# How to Create A "Piecemail" Table From A Conref Table

Tags: xml, dita

Good morning!

I am attempting to create a large table that I can conref bits and pieces in for smaller subsections, but I'm running into a little trouble. Here's what I'm doing, essentially:

Data File:

```
<table colsep="1" frame="topbot" rowsep="1">
    <tgroup cols="2" colsep="1" outputclass="NoTitle" rowsep="1">
      <colspec colname="1" colnum="1" colwidth="13*"/>

      <colspec colname="2" colnum="2" colwidth="87*"/>

      <thead id="Table_C_Header">
        <row rowsep="1">
          <entry colname="1"><p>Foo</p></entry>

          <entry colname="2"><p>Bar</p></entry>
        </row>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <row id="C_Item1" rowsep="1">
          <entry colname="1"><p>Foo1</p></entry>

          <entry colname="2"><ul>
              <li><p>Bar</p><p>Two</p></li>
            </ul></entry>
        </row>

        <row id="C_Item2" rowsep="1">
          <entry colname="1"><p>Foo2</p></entry>

          <entry colname="2"><ul>
              <li><p>Foo Two</p></li>
            </ul></entry>
        </row>
      </tbody>
    </tgroup>
  </table>
```

Other File:

```
<table colsep="1" frame="topbot" rowsep="1">
        <tgroup cols="2" colsep="1" outputclass="NoTitle" rowsep="1">
          <colspec colname="1" colnum="1" colwidth="13*"/>

          <colspec colname="2" colnum="2" colwidth="87*"/>

    <thead conref="/Path/ToDatafile.xml#Table_C_Header />
```

However, the conref does not appear to be working. While I'm open to the fact that this could be an error based on filename path (I am still learning my way around DITA), I am unsure if anything else could be at play.

Essentially, my goal is to have a large table that I can conref by row as needed. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, have to give this one up to simple syntax error. After fighting a bit, I realized that instead of:

```
<thead conref="/Path/ToDatafile.xml#Table_C_Header />
```

I should be using:

```
<thead conref="/Path/ToDatafile.xml#TopicID/Table_C_Header" />
```

Comment: The conref is missing also quotation mark, but I guess, that you noticed it? :)

Comment: I did notice it! Two instances of basic syntax, arg! Thank you for answering!